# Forced Parameterization in Sql Server. Can datetime and uniqueidentifier be inferred from natural string format?

Tags: sql-server, parameter

Reading about the Data Type of parameters inferred when the Forced Parameterization is set, the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver16#data-types-of-parameters) doesn't mention either datetime or uniqueidentifier. It seems that these two data types cannot be inferred from natural string formats. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 3):

If the predicate is a string literal then the inferred parameter type will be a string (`varchar` or `nvarchar` type)

SQL Server won't look at the string contents and infer that it is intended to be a `datetime` or `uniqueidentifier`.

The string datatypes have very low [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) though so if the context of their usage is comparing against a `datetime` or `uniqueidentifier` column they will get implicitly cast to that datatype.

If you want to be more explicit about the intention you can add a `CAST` to the string yourself rather than relying on the implicit cast.

Due to the order of datatype precedence the guessing could be annoying and cause errors and prevent index usage in the case that a column was a string datatype and you just happened to be passing a string that looked like something of a GUID/Datetime.

The ODBC escape sequence formats of `{guid '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'}` and `{ts '2011-09-15 01:23:56.123'}` do also exist but I'm not sure how well they will play with forced parameterisation.

Comment: ODBC escape doesn't get parameterized, and casting still uses `varchar(8000)`, and if you do `0x` you get `varbinary(8000)` see https://dbfiddle.uk/ggQrKmvM

Comment: The casting wasn't to change the parameter datatype. It was to make the cast more explicit. Not sure what the relevance of 0x is to anything in either the question or my answer

Comment: I understand, I was just trying to make that clear. I was also trying to point out to anyone thinking to try a different data type that `varbinary` doesn't help either.